# Нахождение наибольших произведений в массиве строк

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
#include <iostream>

double getVolume(double a, double b, double c) {
    return (a * b * c);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    char information[20][1000] =
    {
        " 25) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 26) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 27) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 9) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 1) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 2) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 3) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 4) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 5) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 6) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 7) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 8) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 11) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 12) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 13)  Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 14) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 15) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 16) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 18) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 19) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см"
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

     }

}
```

Дан вот такой массив. В начале строки стоит номер вещи. Подскажите, как найти номера, у которых произведение ширины, высоты и длинны будет наибольшим?

Comment: Вытаскивать из каждой строки значения размеров, множить, запоминать наибольшее...

Comment: а чем пользоваться чтобы вытащить значение размера? Я понимаю что после слова длина идёт размер, но он может быть равен 60, а может быть равен 60.38. Какой функцией воспользоваться?

Comment: Да хоть `>>`, хоть `sscanf` (тоже в С++ работает), хоть `stod`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ------------ //
// - Item.hpp - //
// ------------ //
#ifndef __ITEM_HPP__
#define __ITEM_HPP__

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Item {
    int id;

    double width;
    double length;
    double height;
    double product;

    bool operator<(const Item&) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Item&);
};

#endif

// ------------ //
// - Item.cpp - //
// ------------ //

// #include "Item.hpp"

bool Item::operator<(const Item& other) const {
    return product < other.product;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Item& it) {
    out << '(' << it.id << ", ";
    out << it.width << ", " << it.length << ", ";
    out << it.height << ", " << it.product << ')';
    return out;
}

// --------------- //
// - Process.hpp - //
// --------------- //
#ifndef __PROCESS_HPP__
#define __PROCESS_HPP__

// #include "Item.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool isNumber(const char&);
void get_value(char*&, int&, double&);
std::vector<Item> process(char*, int, int);

template<typename F>
void go_to(char*& arr, int& j, F&& cond) {
    while(cond(arr[j]))
        ++j;
}

template<typename T>
void get_number(char*& arr, int& j, T& target) {
    target = 0;
    while(isNumber(arr[j])) {
        target *= 10;
        target += arr[j] - '0';
        ++j;
    }
}

#endif

// --------------- //
// - Process.cpp - //
// --------------- //

// #include "Process.hpp"

bool isNumber(const char& c) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

void get_value(char*& arr, int& j, double& target) {
    (void) go_to(arr, j, [] (const char& c) -> bool { return c != '-'; });
    j += 2;

    (void) get_number<double>(arr, j, target);

    if (arr[j] == '.') {
        ++j;
        double temp = 10;

        while(isNumber(arr[j])) {
            target += (arr[j] - '0') / temp;

            ++j;
            temp *= 10;
        }
    }
}

std::vector<Item> process(char* arr, int rows, int cols) {
    std::vector<Item> res;
    
    Item val;
    for(int j = 0, i = 0; i < rows; ++i, j = 1000 * i) {
        (void) go_to(arr, j, [] (const char& c) -> bool { return !isNumber(c); });

        (void) get_number<int>(arr, j, val.id);

        (void) get_value(arr, j, val.width);
        (void) get_value(arr, j, val.length);
        (void) get_value(arr, j, val.height);

        val.product = val.width * val.length * val.height;
        res.push_back(val);
    }
    std::sort(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
    return res;
}

// ------------ //
// - main.cpp - //
// ------------ //

// #include "Process.hpp"

int main() {
    char information[20][1000] =
    {
        " 25) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 26) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 27) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 9) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 1) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 2) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 3) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 4) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 5) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 6) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 7) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 8) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 11) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 12) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 13)  Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 14) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 15) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 16) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 18) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 19) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см"
    };
    
    std::vector<Item> vec = process(&information[0][0], 20, 1000);

    for(Item& it: vec)
        std::cout << it << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```